# Сохранить данные в Excel

Tags: java, excel, оптимизация, apache-poi

Есть сервис, который сохраняет данные из `List` в файл Excel. Проблема в том, что даже небольшой объем данных примерно 1000 записей сохраняется очень долго. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то оптимизировать мой код?

```
@Service
public class ReportsItem {
    private XSSFWorkbook workbook;
    private XSSFSheet sheet;

    @Autowired
    public ReportsItem() {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    }

    public void getAllItems(List<Item> list) {
        generateItemExcelFile(list);
    }

    //Метод создает заголовки в Excel документе
    private void writeItemsHeader() {
        sheet = workbook.createSheet("Items");
        Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setBold(true);
        font.setFontHeight(11);
        style.setFont(font);
        createCell(row,0, "desc", style);
        createCell(row,1, "number", style);
        createCell(row,2, "fio", style);
        createCell(row,3, "birthDate", style);
        createCell(row,4, "date_in", style);
        createCell(row,5, "date_out", style);
        createCell(row,6, "refreason", style);
        createCell(row,7, "price", style);
        createCell(row,8, "service", style);
        createCell(row,9, "allsum", style);
        createCell(row,10, "type", style);
        createCell(row,11, "razdel", style);
        createCell(row,12, "sotrcode", style);
        createCell(row,13, "idnum", style);
        createCell(row,14, "idhistory", style);
        createCell(row,15, "comment", style);
    }

    //Метод записывает в Excel
    private void writeItems(List<Item> list) {
        int rowCount = 1;
        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontHeight(11);
        style.setFont(font);

        for (Item item : list) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCount++);
            int columnCount = 0;
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getDesc(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getNumber(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getFio(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getBirthDate(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getDate_in(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getDate_out(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getRefreason(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getPrice(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getService(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getAllSum(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getType(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getRazdel(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getSotrcode(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getIdnum(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getNhistory(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getComment(), style);
        }
    }
    
    
    //Метод создает ячейку
    private void createCell(Row row, int columnCount, Object valueOfCell, CellStyle style) {
        sheet.autoSizeColumn(columnCount);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(columnCount);
        if (valueOfCell instanceof Integer) {
            cell.setCellValue((Integer) valueOfCell);
        } else if (valueOfCell instanceof Long) {
            cell.setCellValue((Long) valueOfCell);
        } else if (valueOfCell instanceof String) {
            cell.setCellValue((String) valueOfCell);
        } else if (valueOfCell instanceof LocalDate) {
            cell.setCellValue((LocalDate) valueOfCell);
        } else if (valueOfCell instanceof Double) {
            cell.setCellValue((Double) valueOfCell);
        } else if (valueOfCell instanceof Boolean){
            cell.setCellValue((Boolean) valueOfCell);
        }
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
    }

    //Сохраняем файл в Excel формат
    private void generateItemExcelFile(List<Item> list) {
        String fileName = "report-" + LocalDate.now() + ".xlsx";

        File dir = new File(AppConstants.reportsFilePath);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(AppConstants.reportsFilePath + fileName);
             BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream)) {
            writeItemsHeader();
            writeItems(list);
            workbook.write(bufferedOutputStream);
            workbook.close();
            AlertDialogUtils.showInfoAlert("Информация", null, "Файл отчета успешно сформирован в: " + AppConstants.reportsFilePath + fileName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: В принципе разобрался, использовать SXSSFWorkbook и SXSSFSheet вместо XSSFWorkbook и XSSFSheet.

Comment: Можете написать тогда ответ на свой же вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Сделал так, быстрее стало работать.

```
@Service
public class ReportsItem {
    private SXSSFWorkbook workbook;
    private SXSSFSheet sheet;

    @Autowired
    public ReportsItem() {
        workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook();
    }

    public void getAllItems(List<Item> list) {
        generateItemExcelFile(list);
    }

    //Метод создает заголовки в Excel документе
    private void writeItemsHeader() {
        sheet = workbook.createSheet("Items");
        SXSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        Font font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setBold(true);
        font.setFontHeight(11);
        style.setFont(font);
        createCell(row,0, "desc", style);
        createCell(row,1, "number", style);
        createCell(row,2, "fio", style);
        createCell(row,3, "birthDate", style);
        createCell(row,4, "date_in", style);
        createCell(row,5, "date_out", style);
        createCell(row,6, "refreason", style);
        createCell(row,7, "price", style);
        createCell(row,8, "service", style);
        createCell(row,9, "allsum", style);
        createCell(row,10, "type", style);
        createCell(row,11, "razdel", style);
        createCell(row,12, "sotrcode", style);
        createCell(row,13, "idnum", style);
        createCell(row,14, "idhistory", style);
        createCell(row,15, "comment", style);
    }

    //Метод записывает в Excel
    private void writeItems(List<Item> list) {
        int rowCount = 1;
        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        Font font = workbook.createFont();
        style.setFont(font);

        for (Item item : list) {
            SXSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowCount++);
            int columnCount = 0;
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getDesc(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getNumber(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getFio(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getBirthDate(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getDate_in(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getDate_out(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getRefreason(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getPrice(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getService(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getAllSum(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getType(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getRazdel(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getSotrcode(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getIdnum(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getNhistory(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, item.getComment(), style);
        }
    }
    
    
    //Метод создает ячейку
    private void createCell(SXSSFRow row, int columnCount, Object valueOfCell, CellStyle style) {
        SXSSFCell cell = row.createCell(columnCount);
        if (valueOfCell instanceof Integer) {
            cell.setCellValue((Integer) valueOfCell);
        } else if (valueOfCell instanceof Long) {
            cell.setCellValue((Long) valueOfCell);
        } else if (valueOfCell instanceof String) {
            cell.setCellValue((String) valueOfCell);
        } else if (valueOfCell instanceof LocalDate) {
            cell.setCellValue((LocalDate) valueOfCell);
        } else if (valueOfCell instanceof Double) {
            cell.setCellValue((Double) valueOfCell);
        } else if (valueOfCell instanceof Boolean){
            cell.setCellValue((Boolean) valueOfCell);
        }
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
    }

    //Сохраняем файл в Excel формат
    private void generateItemExcelFile(List<Item> list) {
        String fileName = "report-" + LocalDate.now() + ".xlsx";

        File dir = new File(AppConstants.reportsFilePath);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(AppConstants.reportsFilePath + fileName);
             BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream)) {
            writeItemsHeader();
            writeItems(list);
            workbook.write(bufferedOutputStream);
            workbook.close();
            AlertDialogUtils.showInfoAlert("Информация", null, "Файл отчета успешно сформирован в: " + AppConstants.reportsFilePath + fileName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

}
```